# How to solve the Dimension issue regarding reloading of the VGG16 model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using VGG16 model for making a classifier on cats and dogs. I have modified the last layer of the model to have 2 nodes instead of 1000 nodes. I am saving the model here:

**model.save('CNNFromScratch.h5')**

and loading it in another file by:

**new_model = load_model('CNNFromScratch.h5')**

And I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1567, in _create_c_op
>       c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:
>   Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 4096 and 1000.
>   Shapes are [4096,2] and [1000,2]. for 'Assign_30' (op: 'Assign') with
>   input shapes: [4096,2], [1000,2].

.
**What can I do to solve the problem?**